# how do you add multiple versions of the same assembly to the gac

Tags: .net, assemblies, gac, csla

My one ASP.NET web site uses two different business object class libraries. There is a common framework DLL (CSLA.dll) between these two libraries. The problem is that one library wants to upgrade to CSLA v.4.0.1 and the other wants to remain at v.2.1.4.

How do I solve this conflict at the web site? I think I need to install both versions of the CSLA into the GAC, but I don't know how to do two things

1. Add different versions of the same DLL to the GAC (I have used `gacutil -i` on both CSLA.dlls. I see CSLA.dll 2.1.4 in the .NET Configuration 2.0 tool, but I see CSLA.dll 4.0.1 in `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Csla`
2. Make the web site reference the two different versions

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Ok, i just learned that .NET GAC is different with .NET 4.0. I would probably have to note an assumption -- my web site and business objects are all targeting .NET 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to:

> Make the web site reference the two different versions

You can force your application to use a specific version of an assembly by using Assembly Binding Redirection:

- [Assembly Binding Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Configuring Assembly Binding Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/433ysdt1.aspx)
- [The assemblyBinding config element.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e.aspx)

In your case, the configuration should go in your web.config since the redirection is application-specific and doesn't apply to an entire version of the framework.